# How to posting Images bytes from javascript to JAX-RS websevice and create BufferedImage from imageBytes array?

Tags: javascript, java, image, jax-rs, bufferedimage

I would like to send image bytes from a Javascript client to a JAX-RS web service. I tried encoding the image bytes using the Javascript `btoa()` function, and at server-side tried to create a `BufferedImage` like

```
ByteArrayInputStream arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(arrayInputStream);
```

However, originalImage is getting as null.

Could you please help me.

**Full Code:**

**Javascript:**

```js
function handleUpload(){
  var input = document.getElementById("imageUploadId");
  var file = input.files[0];
  file.convertToBase64(base64ImageData);
}

function base64ImageData(data){
  if(data){
    var imageBytes = data.split(",")[1];
    imageBytes =  btoa(imageBytes);
  }
}
```

**Java - Jax-RS :**

```
String ImageByteFromrequest ="";
byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decode(ImageByteFromrequest);
ByteArrayInputStream arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(arrayInputStream);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post all your code.. you have tried till now

Comment: Hi SK, code updated, could you please check.

Comment: any specific reason to use only bytearray?

Comment: i need to scale the image.

Comment: Hi Prasobh, why can't you use formData? like 
var formData = new FormData(input.files[0]);

Comment: Show the whole code where you are sending the request and show the whole JAX-RS resource method.